# linux shell script sed css structure

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

how do I write the following sed command so that I can use the line breaks and code structure when I write the sed command as well as output the same 
code structure? As you can see I'm trying to modify CSS without making it one line.

```
sed -i 's/#para3{ 
font-size:21pt;    
position:absolute; 
width:500px; 
left:15px;
top:445px; 
text-align:left;
  }/#para3{ 
font-size:testpt;    
position:absolute; 
width:500px; 
left:15px;
top:445px; 
text-align:left;
  }/g' $file0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to replace `font-size` value between `#para3 {` and next `}`:

```
sed '/#para3 *{/,/}/{s/\(font-size: *\)21pt;/\1testpt;/}' file
```

To replace all block, you can try the `c`(change) command:

```
sed '/#para3 *{/,/}/c \
#para3 { \
  font-size: 3em; \
  width: 100%; \
}' file
```

NB: after the `c` command, all lines except last one must ends with a  newline character (`\`)

Comment: This is  a great answer and I'll definitely use it but I want to replace everything between #para3{ and  next }

Comment: why does the 1 get replaced ?1testpt;  is replaced with testpt;

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you proceed in the following way:

- Store the content of your css replacement patterns in 2 files (the part to be replaced and the part that will be used for the replacement operation)
- Use the `cat` command to get the files content and store it in 2 variables `var1="$(cat toReplace.css)"; var2="$(cat replacement.css)"`
- Use the 2 variables when calling the sed command: `sed -i.bak "s/$var1/$var2/g" $file0`
- Since you are using the in-place replacement it might be better to take a backup of your file!
- Last but not least, you will have to escape all the characters that might be interpreted as special character in your regex as `{}` you just have to add a backslash before them.

Comment: I still get the following error                                                                     
                                                                                                               
       sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unterminated `s' command